# How can I tell if a WPF bitmap image has failed to load?

Tags: c#, wpf, imaging

I'm using the following code to load an image from file into a bitmap image class to display to the user at a particular size:

```
                BitmapImage resized = new BitmapImage();
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(ImageSource, FileMode.Open);
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                fs.CopyTo(ms);
                fs.Close();
                resized.BeginInit();
                resized.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnDemand;
                resized.DecodePixelHeight = (int)(_imageBaseHeight * zoomRate);
                resized.DecodePixelWidth = (int)(_imageBaseWidth * zoomRate);
                resized.StreamSource = ms;
                resized.EndInit();
                ImageDisplay = resized;
```

The problem is that sometimes, on particularly large images, this will fail silently and display a blank image without raising an exception. Is there a flag that I can check after EndInit() to be sure the image has loaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [resized.DownloadFailed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.downloadfailed.aspx) event to get informed.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like it's been happening on DecodeFailed. Is there a way to display messages to the user from these handlers? It looks like they both happen out of the UI thread.

Comment: @Dan: Use something like: Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { /*Her comes your action*/ }), DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle);

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the ImageFailed event.